# $f\in\mathcal{S}'^n$, if $D^\alpha f\in L^2$, prove $\xi^\alpha\hat f(\xi)\in L^2$

Tags: functional-analysis, fourier-analysis, fourier-transform, distribution-theory

Suppose $f\in\mathcal{S}'((\mathbb{R}^n))$, if $D^\alpha f\in L^2(\mathbb{R}^n)$, prove $\xi^\alpha\hat f(\xi)\in L^2(\mathbb{R}^n)$.

I know $F[D^\alpha f]=\xi^\alpha\hat f(\xi)$, so I want to prove
$$
\int_{\mathbb{R}^n_x}\left(\int_{\mathbb{R}^n_y} e^{ixy}D^\alpha f(y)dy\right)^2dx<+\infty.
$$
How to prove it?

Comment: Do you know Plancherel formula?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know.

Comment: Consult it and you will immediately find the answer